# Differentiate between button touch and screen touch

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine, touch

I am making simple game in witch a player touches anywhere on the screen to do something. It is a kind of reflex game. At the same time I have button on the screen that allows to pause a game. The problem is that when I touch a button a game detects a screen touch at the same time and I would like to avoid that. I use a boolean that I change on button press but it still doesnt work properrly - game is paused just a fraction of the second after the screen touch is detected.

My pause game code:

```
GameControlerScript:

public static bool isPaused;
public void PauseGame()
    {
        isPaused = true; // this is static
        Time.timeScale = 0.0f;

        //more code here

    }
```

and my touch detection in the script attached to different object:

```
void Update()
    {

        if (((Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) || (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))) && !GameControllerScript.isPaused)
        {
             // code here starts to be executed and then pasues because of timescale
        }

    }
```

So is there a way to make get the change to the isPaused boolean before it detects scrren touch?

Comment: Are those two functions in the same class/game object? Because you can just add a text that if isPaused==true it just return;s so the next code doesn't get executed... Am I missing something?

Comment: Thats the thing that both codes are attached to different objects. First one is a script of kind of game manager that holds a game logic and the second is attached to the obbject that is instantiated during gameplay (but always only one of this kind). If it would be one gameobject I would put all into one script and manage with simple boolean, but not in this case

Comment: if you have a game manager object (let's say it has a component named GameManager and inside that component there is the isPaused boolean). Make the boolean non static and public, then you can access it through the other object using GameObject.Find("game manager").GetComponent<GameManager>().isPaused

Comment: Is the fact that it is static and I acces it by GameControllerScript.isPaused causing a problem?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, but I'm not sure it it'll work. If it works, everything you have to do is to insert: if (GameControllerScript.isPaused) return; into the Update() function. Right? Or I missed something? Where is the isPaused boolean located? in the game manager or the gameobject?

Comment: is paused is located in the script of game object, the first one in my question. Ill edit my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109732/discussion-between-yotam-salmon-and-lukasz-motyczka).

Comment: when you say "BUTTON ON SCREEN" you mean you are using unity UI right ?

Comment: Yes. There is a UI button. I use its onClick to call the PauseGame() in the GameController script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check it your touch is on the UI element then if it isn't call whatever method you call for normal input

```
public void Update()

{
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId))
        {
            // you touched at least one UI element
            return;
        }
    }

    // you didnt touched any UI element
    // Do Something
}
```

Comment: Strange, when I did it like: `if (((Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) || (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))) && !GameControllerScript.isPaused && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())` it did not work propoerly, but it seams to work with your code. :) Thanks!